# Regular expression for strings where each character has equaly times present

Tags: c#, regex

Would it be possible to write a regular expression, that accepts only input strings composed of two characters (A, B) and only those where count of number of A's occurences = number of B's occurences? Regardless of order. I have really hard time trying to figure it out.

For example:

```
AB -> match    
AABB -> match    
ABAB -> match    
AAB -> no match (1A but 2B)    
A -> no match (1A but 0B)
```

Comment: Regex might not be the right tool here.

Comment: Check the distink letters and cout them

Comment: Not a *regular* [balanced expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html): [`^(?>(?'x'A)+(?'-x'B)+|(?'x'B)+(?'-x'A)+)+(?(x)(?!))$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3e%28%3f%27x%27A%29%2b%28%3f%27-x%27B%29%2b%7c%28%3f%27x%27B%29%2b%28%3f%27-x%27A%29%2b%29%2b%28%3f%28x%29%28%3f!%29%29%24&i=AB)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this result using a [balancing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions) technique with this regex:

```
^(?=(?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))+)(?>(?<-a>B)|(?<-b>A))+$
```

This regex first uses a lookahead `(?=(?:(?<a>A)|(?<b>B))+)` to store all occurrences of `A` and `B` into their appropriate `a` and `b` stacks. It then matches each character in turn using `(?>(?<-a>B)|(?<-b>A))+`, popping an `A` off the stack when a `B` is encountered, and a `B` off the stack when an `A` is encountered. If at any time we run out of characters in a stack to pop (i.e. when there are mismatched numbers of `A` and `B`), the attempt to pop will fail and so will the match.

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wzArU8/1)

Answer (score -2):

No it's not possible to do that with just a regex pattern.